# FlatOut 2 - Race track length

Tags: pc, flatout-2

I would like to know if there is any way to determine the length of any race track in the game FlatOut 2 ?

My question is as simple as that! But I doubt any answer can be found easily...

Any help would be appreciated !

PS: Sorry for the lame tagging, but no one has ever created the "flatout-2" tag, and I am not allowed to do so due to my low reputation.

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully you mean the music tracks and not the race tracks!

Here you go:

1. Alkaline Trio - Fall Victim - 3:18
2. The Chelsea Smiles - Nowhere Ride - 3:38
3. Papa Roach - Blood Brothers - 3:32
4. Supergrass - Road To Rouen - 3:48
5. Alkaline Trio - Mercy Me - 2:49
6. Nickelback - Believe It or Not - 4:08
7. Megadeth - Symphony of Destruction - 4:05
8. Yellowcard - Rough landing Holly - 3:32
9. Yellowcard - Breathing - 3:38
10. Zebrahead - Lobotomy for Dummies - 2:38
11. Rise Against - Give It All - 2:49
12. Papa Roach - Not Listening - 3:09
13. Underoath - Reinventing Your Exit - 4:24
14. Fall Out Boy - 7 Minutes In Heaven - 3:02
15. Supergrass - Richard III - 3:05
16. Nickelback - Flat on The Floor - 2:03
17. Rob Zombie - Feel So Numb - 3:33
18. Rob Zombie - Demon Speeding - 3:29
19. Wolfmother - Pyramid - 4:29
20. Wolfmother - Dimension - 4:22
21. Fall Out Boy - Snitches,and Talkers Get Stitched - 2:49
22. The Vines - Don't Listen To The Radio - 2:11
23. Motley Crue - DrFeelgood - 4:50
24. Audioslave - Man or Animal - 3:45
25. Audioslave - Your Time Has Come - 4:13

I am not promoting illegal downloading of the soundtrack, I am just quoting my source: [Flatout 2 OST torrent](http://extratorrent.com/torrent/1351216/Flatout+2+OST.html) (either way this torrent is dead as it ran out of seeders).

Comment: Thank for your answer, but I was talking about the race tracks... I have edited my question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

With all its different routes for each track, I think such information would be fairly subjective.
Despite that, I just unpacked the game's data files with [BFS2Unpacker](http://flatoutjoint.com/index.php?option=com_remository&func=fileinfo&id=115) and looked for any indication of race track lengths. No luck.

Comment: Ok thanks for your patience. I will continue my investigations.

Comment: @Hal: Good luck! If you do succeed, please post back with your findings.